# How can I insert values into list<text> column in Cassandra column family, using Thrift (Java)

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

Hi I have following columnfamily at Cassandra

```
COLUMNFAMILY  aaaa (  aa int,  aaa list<int>,  bbb list<boolean>,zzzz int, xxx map<text ,int>, sssss list<int>, PRIMARY KEY (aa));
```

How could I fill all list' and map' columns using Thrift Java?

Answer (score 1):

While this may be technically possible, it would require a lot of application side complexity which could be totally avoided if you just use a cql compatible client.

Bottom line,
Collections are a CQL feature, modify them with CQL clients.

Comment: Great, do you know how to do it via Hector?